# Rendering script from partial template in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a partial template that contains a `<script src='....'/>` tag in it.
When user clicks a button I need to render partial template in modal. 
so here is my code:

**List.html**

```
<script src="App/controllers/detailsCtrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<h3 class="page-header">All Websites</h3>
<br />
<div ng-app="app" class="" ng-controller="listCtrl" data-ng-init="init();">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="" ng-click="order('Name')">Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="" ng-click="order('DisplayName')">Display Name</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="" ng-click="order('DateTime')">Created On</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="" ng-click="order('FK_Name')">Source Site</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="" ng-click="order('State')">State</a>
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <tr ng-repeat="website in model | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate">
                    <td>{{website.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{website.DisplayName}}</td>
                    <td>{{website.DateTime | creationDateFilter | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}</td>
                    <td>{{website.FK_Name | sourceSiteFilter}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on active"
                           ng-if="website.State == 'Started'"
                           ng-click="changeState(website)">
                        </i>
                        <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-rotate-180 inactive"
                           ng-if="website.State == 'Stopped'"
                           ng-click="changeState(website)">
                        </i>
                    <td style="text-align:center">

                        <a href="/Replicate/Edit/{{website.Id}}" ng-disabled="{{website.Id}}==0"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="showDetails(website.Name)"><i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"></i></a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-if="model.length == 0">
                    <td colspan="6" class="text-center"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <center>
            <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"
                        max-size="5" boundary-links="true"
                        items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">
            </pagination>
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**listCtrl.js**

```
//open modal and shows details of single object
    $scope.showDetails = function (websiteName) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/details.html',
            controller: 'detailsCtrl',
            resolve: {
                obj: function () {
                    return websiteFactory.getFilteredObject($scope.model, websiteName);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**details.html**

```
<div ng-controller="detailsCtrl">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Website Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="details">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Display Name</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.DisplayName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.Description}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Created On</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.DateTime | creationDateFilter | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a'}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Source Website</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.FK_Name}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Current State</td>
                    <td>{{singleObject.State}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--@*<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>*@-->
    </div>
</div>
```

**detailsCtrl.js**

```
app.controller('detailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'obj', function ($scope, $modalInstance, obj) {
    $scope.singleObject = {
        Name: obj.Name,
        DisplayName: obj.DisplayName,
        DateTime: obj.DateTime,
        FK_Name: obj.FK_Name,
        State: obj.State,
        Description: obj.Description
    };
    $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

**Error**

Argument 'detailsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined.

If I include this script tag to index.html(my main view page). Everything works.
Problem is that I am adding the script tag but I know script is not rendering. why is this so? How can I lazyload the script file. Or should I always add all the js files to the main view (index.html)?

Comment: where is your app module defined??

Comment: you may want to try OCLazyLoad module: https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs

Comment: @Aravind I have defined that in seperate file. naming app.js

Comment: For this you need to include the script tag only when the button is clicked. As the required js is on the unloaded page it doesn't know what to do when the button is clicked. May be this link  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp or as Andri said you try lazy load

Comment: this is not working! 
Thanks